# Finding all tangent lines to circle $x^2+y^2=9$ having exactly one common point with parabola $y=x^2+3$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

> I have to find all tangent lines to the circle $x^2+y^2=9$, which have exactly one common point with the parabola $y=x^2+3$.

I drew it and I saw that $(0,3)$ is a common point circle and parabola. I found that three tangent lines are: $y=3$, $x=-3$, $x=3$. And now the question is whether these are all? I don't know how to explain it or find others lines.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any given point on the circle, there is a unique tangent line.  At the point $(0,3)$ you have identified 3.  Only one is tangent.

The other lines:

[image]

Since this is tagged pre-calculus, I will not use calculus in this answer.

Suppose $x_1,y_1$ lies on the circle.

Slope of the tangent line though that point is negative reciprocal of the slope of the radius.

$m = -\frac {x_1}{y_1}$

Equations of the tangent line in point slope and y-intercept form:

$y-y_1 = -\frac {x_1}{y_1} (x-x_1)\\
y = -\frac {x_1}{y_1} x + \frac {x_1^2 +y_1^2}{y_1}\\
y = -\frac {x_1}{y_1} x + \frac {9}{y_1}\\
$

Remember $x_1,y_1$ lie on the circle so $x_1^2 + y_1^2 = 9$  we will be using this fact a couple more times.

The line is also tangent to $y = x^2 + 3$

Substituting:

$-\frac {x_1}{y_1} x + \frac {9}{y_1} = x^2 + 3\\
y_1x^2 + x_1x + 3y_1 - 9 = 0$

Since our line is tangent, when we plug this into the quadratic formula, we must get exactly one root.  i.e. $b^2 - 4ac = 0$.

$x_1^2 - 4y_1(3y_1-9) = 0\\
x_1^2 + 36y_1 - 12y_1^2 = 0$

We can use $x_1^2+ y_1^2 = 9$ again. Substitute $x_1^2 = 9 - y_1^2$

$(9-y_1^2) + 36y_1 - 12y_1^2 = 0\\
13y_1^2 - 36y_1 - 9 = 0\\
(y_1 - 3)(13y_1 + 3) = 0$

We have two values for $y_1.$  Solve for $x_1.$

$x_1^2 + 9 = 9\\
x_1^2 + \frac {9}{169} = 9$

$(0,3),(\frac {3\sqrt {168}}{13},-\frac {3}{13}), (-\frac {3\sqrt {168}}{13},-\frac {3}{13})$ are our 3 points of tangency.

And, plug into our earlier equations of the tangent lines.

$y = 3\\      
y = \sqrt {168} x - 39\\
y = -\sqrt {168} x - 39$

Comment: what about the tangents to the circle at $x=\pm 3$?

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is really good, but I have the same queations, what about the line $x=3$ and $x=-3$.Are incorrect?

Comment: I understand it this way that for example $x=3$ is a tangent line to the circle and it "cut" parabola in one point. And it is not the tangent line to the parabola, but to circle for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Any point on the parabola : $P(a,a^2+3)$

The equation of the tangent at $P$ will be $$\dfrac{y-(a^2+3)}{x-a}=2a$$

$$\iff2ax-y+3-a^2=0$$

To be a tangent of the circle, the distance from the centre needs to be equal to the radius

$$3=\dfrac{|3-a^2|}{\sqrt{(2a)^2+(-1)^2}}$$

Take square in both sides and solve for $a$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = ax+b$ be such a line. A pair $(a, b)$ forms a solution if the corresponding line intersects both the parabola and the circle in exactly one point each. So, substituting $y$ in each curve equation:

$(ax+b)^2 + x^2 = 9$ must have only one solution: discriminant, in terms of a and b, is zero.

$(ax+b)= x^2 +3$ must have only one solution: discriminant, in terms of a and b, is zero.

You then get a system of equations, which is very straightforward:

$9a^2=b^2-9$

$a^2=4(3-b)$

Observe that, if $(a, b)$ is a solution, so is $(-a, b)$, as the curves are geometrically simmetric towards y axis.

EDIT

Vertical lines are not checked for solution in the former assumption that $y = ax+b$. Setting $x = k$, constant, should find the other lines you got from the beginning.